# Dom element ignoring the text inside Angular brackets <>

Tags: javascript, html, dom, combobox, dojo

I have a dijit/form/ComboBox which have a store with following value:

[image: dijit comboBox store data]

The issue is that in this dropdown the values are coming up as blank instead of the names as in the data store("",""). Is this due to the brackets <, >? If yes then how it can be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are so called "htmlspecialchars" you are able to display what you want using htmlentities:

`Try &lt; (<) and &gt; (>)`

So it would be:

`&lt;b&gt;`which display as `<b>`

@see https://www.htmlhelp.com/de/reference/html40/entities/special.html

Comment: Actually, this value(<b>) is getting populated using a data structure which has the value pre-defined as <b> which I cannot change.....